# C - Comparing variable with sizeof(int)

Tags: c, pipe

So, recently I saw a piece of C code as the following:

```
int result, input;


result = read(fd, (char*)&input, sizeof(input));

if(result == sizeof(int)) return input;
```

What does the comparison `result == sizeof(int)` do?

Comment: just checking if `result` has been fully read. That's all

Comment: check the answers.

Comment: .. and the [`read` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read)

Comment: of course the shown code is crazy cos it overwrites what it just read with the read length

Comment: @pm100 Ues, I noticed & editted that. Thank you.

Comment: std::iostream::read returns a reference to iostream.  I'd be surprised if that was only the size of an integer.

Comment: @mreff555: I'd be surprised if the C compiler had any idea what a `std:iostream` was.

Comment: It checks whether `result` and `sizeof(int)` have the same value... just like `1+1 == 2` checks whether `1+1` and `2` have the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` returns the number of bytes read (or `-1` on error). The code is attempting to read an `int` from a stream, and it's making sure the `read` worked properly.

Answer (score 2):

`read` returns the number of bytes read.

In some cases (end of file, disk error, broken pipe), `read` could return less than the size of the integer requested in the call, or `-1` to indicate an error.

That's just a sanity check to ensure the integrity of `input`

Personally I would have prefered to test against `sizeof(input)` because if the type of `input` changes for `short` or `double`, then the code wrongly detects a read-size problem.

Comment: So that's why read may return multiple positive values...  Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This makes it clearer

```
int readLength;
int readData; // or long, float, ...

readLength = read(fd, (char*)&readData, sizeof(readData));

if(readLength == sizeof(readData)) // Do something
```

The original code was broken due to its reuse of `result`